# suggestion on table format in c++

Tags: c++

I need to add a table format for my current code. I have somewhat simpler version of the code below.

```
class A {
  public:
    A():x(0) {
    } int getValue() {
    return x;
    }
  private:
    int x;
};

class B {
  public:
    B():y(0) {
    } int getValue() {
    return y;
    }
  private:
    int y;
};

class C {
  public:
    C():z(0) {
    } int getValue() {
    return z;
    }
  private:
    int z;
};

class D {
  public:
    D(A x, B y, C z) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    c = z;
    } A getA() {
    return a;
    }
    B getB() {
    return b;
    }
    C getC() {
    return c;
    }
  private:
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

typedef enum {
    TABLE_A = 0,
    TABLE_B,
    TABLE_C,
    TABLE_D,
    TABLE_MAX
} table_index;

typedef struct tableInfo_tag {
    table_index id, D d;
} tableInfo;

tableInfo gtable[table_index::TABLE_MAX] = {
    {TABLE_A, {1, 2, 3}},
    {TABLE_A, {4, 5, 6}},
    {TABLE_A, {7, 8, 9}}
}
```

But my somehow i cannot give the values in the table for the class D, as it accepts constructor. I need to have this table format, as i can give large range of set of values and get the set depending on certain conditions...I am not a c++ expert, so any input on how to proceed further Or any other ideas/inputs are really very helpful

Comment: Where is the type(!) `table_index` defined? `typedef tableInfo_tag {...} tableInfo;` doesn't compile either. Please show real code. BTW: I think your problem would be solved by simply using plain structs, as these can easily be initialized from the `{}` list, even under the old C++ standard.

Comment: thanks for the comments.just corrected. Unfortunately i cannot show the original code ( eventhough i have written this part of it) as it is part of large project code. I just wanted to add table version to the existing c++ code, so class is preferred. The class D is already defined..so i need to see , how best to add a table of values of D...

Comment: I have to add that your code is very hard to read. You should give variables and types meaningful names and format your code for people to read rather than compilers only.

Comment: C++11 or smaller? if latter, you'll need to make `D` plain old type: no user defined constructor, no privates... Then you can use C-style initialization list. The same applies to `A`, `B`, `C`... If former you can get this syntax using so called initializer list, look up `std::initializer_list`

Comment: thanks, will have look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct tableInfo_tag {
    table_index id;
    D d;
} tableInfo;

tableInfo gtable[TABLE_MAX] = {
    {TABLE_A, D(A(),B(),C())}
};
```

it was fun writing again some c ;)

```
typedef struct tableInfo_tag {
    table_index id;
    int d_len;
    D d[8];
} tableInfo;

tableInfo gtable[TABLE_MAX] = {
    {TABLE_A, 2, {D(A(),B(),C()),D()}}
};
```

here ^^^ d is an array, but it should be statically allocated - that's why it's size should be specified...the usable size of D is unknown, i added d_len to work around this...

Comment: well now there is one more issue. when i was trying to implement this on my code, i realised that, i have a vector of class type D for each table. The vector sizes can vary.                    typedef struct tableInfo_tag { 
    table_index id; int num_instances;
    D d;
} tableInfo;

tableInfo gtable[TABLE_MAX] = {
    {TABLE_A, 1, D(A(),B(),C())}, {TABLE_B, 2, D(A(),B(),C()),  D(A(),B(),C())}
};

Comment: Basically I want to specify the number of instances of D to be variable in the table and read those and create a vector.